# What is that? That’s the price

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Could you say that it's an idiomatic dialogue, or something is awkward, for example, pronouns?

-- **But there is a problem.**
-- **What is that?**
-- **That’s the price.**

P.S. I suppose "That’s just the price." a word "just" here would be needless. Am I right? Because if they use "just", it's not a problem for them.

Comment: But there is a problem. -- What? -- The price.   Would be more likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be said, but it's unlikely.  For a start no contractions have been used.  That's not very idiomatic.  The use of "that" is odd on both occasions.

> But there's a problem.
>
> What is it?
>
> The price.

The middle line doesn't need to be a complete question. It could "Go on" or "Mm hmm" or just a raising of the eyebrows.